# Why can't I split combinations/events?

Tags: combinatorics

I was recently struggling with a problem that read as so:

> A club has 30 members work in business and 30 members that are professors. In how many ways can a committee of 8 be selected that has at least 3 in business and at least 3 professors?

For my answer, I first took care of the requirements, then grouped the rest together to get $$\binom{30}{3}\binom{30}{3}\binom{54}{2}$$
Which ended up being wildly wrong from the correct answer which was 
$$\binom{30}{5}\binom{30}{3}*2 +\binom{30}{4}\binom{30}{4}$$
I once again tried splitting the last combination by case to get
$$\binom{30}{3}\binom{30}{3}(\binom{27}{1}\binom{27}{1}+\binom{27}{2}+\binom{27}{2})$$
But this just turned out to be the same as my previous answer. After doing some research, I came to the conclusion that my answers were larger than the correct one because I was splitting the event into many smaller sections, and in doing so, overcounting cases, which is why
$$\binom{10}{3}\neq \binom{10}{2}\binom{8}1$$
I can accept this as a general principle, as the numbers aren't equal. However, it doesn't really logically make sense to me. What am I actually overcounting by splitting up a combination such as $\binom{10}{3}$ into $\binom{10}{1}\binom{9}{1}\binom{8}{1}$? Why does splitting and adding events together have no effect?

Answer (score 3):

Let $b_1,\dots, b_{30}$ be the business men and $p_1,\dots, p_{30}$ the professors and consider the committee $b_1,b_2,b_3,b_4,p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4$. By using the formula $$\binom{30}{3}\binom{30}{3}\binom{54}{2}$$
you will overcount that committee more than one time: one if you first choose the subsets $\{b_1,b_2,b_3\}$ and $\{p_1,p_2,p_3\}$ and then $b_4$ and $p_4$ among the remaining $54$ members, AND another time if you first choose the subsets $\{b_1,b_2,b_4\}$ and $\{p_1,p_2,p_4\}$ and then $b_3$ and $p_3$ among the remaining $54$ members. Actually you will overcount it $4\cdot 4=16$ times.

Instead consider the admissible compositions of the committe: $8=3+5=4+4=5+3$ where the first number is the number of businessmen and the second one the number of professors in the committee. Then the number of such committees is
$$\binom{30}{3}\binom{30}{5} +\binom{30}{4}\binom{30}{4}+\binom{30}{5}\binom{30}{3}.$$

Comment: @drhab Thanks!!